# What's the style for immutable set and map in F#

Tags: f#, coding-style, functional-programming, set

I have just solved [problem23](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=23) in Project Euler, in which I need a *set* to store all abundant numbers. F# has a immutable set, I can use `Set.empty.Add(i)` to create a new set containing number `i`. But I don't know how to use immutable set to do more complicated things.

For example, in the following code, I need to see if a number 'x' could be written as the sum of two numbers in a set. I resort to a sorted array and array's binary search algorithm to get the job done.

Please also comment on my style of the following program. Thanks!

```
let problem23 = 
    let factorSum x =
        let mutable sum = 0
        for i=1 to x/2 do
            if x%i=0 then
                sum <- sum + i
        sum
    let isAbundant x = x < (factorSum x)
    let abuns = {1..28123} |> Seq.filter isAbundant |> Seq.toArray
    let inAbuns x = Array.BinarySearch(abuns, x) >= 0
    let sumable x = 
        abuns |> Seq.exists (fun a -> inAbuns (x-a))
    {1..28123} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (sumable x)) |> Seq.sum
```

the updated version:

```
let problem23b =
    let factorSum x =
        {1..x/2} |> Seq.filter (fun i->x%i=0) |> Seq.sum
    let isAbundant x = x < (factorSum x)
    let abuns = Set( {1..28123} |> Seq.filter isAbundant )
    let inAbuns x = Set.contains x abuns  
    let sumable x = 
        abuns |> Seq.exists (fun a -> inAbuns (x-a))
    {1..28123} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> not (sumable x)) |> Seq.sum
```

This version runs in about 27 seconds, while the first 23 seconds(I've run several times). So an immutable red-black tree actually does not have much speed down compared to a sorted array with binary search. The total number of elements in the set/array is `6965`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create a `Set` from a given sequence of values.

```
let abuns = Set (seq {1..28123} |> Seq.filter isAbundant)
```

`inAbuns` would therefore be rewritten to

```
let inAbuns x = abuns |> Set.mem x
```

`Seq.exists` would be changed to `Set.exists`

But the array implementation is fine too ...

Note that there is no need to use mutable values in `factorSum`, apart from the fact that it's incorrect since you compute the *number* of divisors instead of their sum:

```
let factorSum x = seq { 1..x/2 } |> Seq.filter (fun i -> x % i = 0) |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: Note: `Set.mem` is replaced by `Set.contains` in the most recent versions of F#.

Answer (score 4):

Your style looks fine to me. The different steps in the algorithm are clear, which is the most important part of making something work. This is also the tactic I use for solving Project Euler problems. First make it work, and then make it fast.

As already remarked, replacing Array.BinarySearch by Set.contains makes the code even more readable. I find that in almost all PE solutions I've written, I only use arrays for lookups. I've found that using sequences and lists as data structures is more natural within F#. Once you get used to them, that is.

I don't think using mutability inside a function is necessarily bad. I've optimized problem 155 from almost 3 minutes down to 7 seconds with some aggressive mutability optimizations. In general though, I'd save that as an optimization step and start out writing it using folds/filters etc. In the example case of problem 155, I did start out using immutable function composition, because it made testing and most importantly, understanding, my approach easy.

Picking the wrong algorithm is much more detrimental to a solution than using a somewhat slower immutable approach first. A good algorithm is still fast even if it's slower than the mutable version (*couch* hello captain obvious! *cough*).

*Edit: let's look at your version*

Your problem23b() took 31 seconds on my PC.

Optimization 1: use new algorithm.

```
//useful optimization: if m divides n, (n/m) divides n also
//you now only have to check m up to sqrt(n)
let factorSum2 n = 
    let rec aux acc m =
        match m with
        | m when m*m = n -> acc + m
        | m when m*m > n -> acc
        | m -> aux (acc + (if n%m=0 then m + n/m else 0)) (m+1)
    aux 1 2
```

This is still very much in functional style, but using this updated factorSum in your code, the execution time went from 31 seconds to 8 seconds.

Everything's still in immutable style, but let's see what happens when an array lookup is used instead of a set:

Optimization 2: use an array for lookup:

```
let absums() = 
    //create abundant numbers as an array for (very) fast lookup
    let abnums = [|1..28128|] |> Array.filter (fun n -> factorSum2 n > n)
    //create a second lookup: 
    //a boolean array where arr.[x] = true means x is a sum of two abundant numbers
    let arr = Array.zeroCreate 28124
    for x in abnums do 
        for y in abnums do
            if x+y<=28123 then arr.[x+y] <- true
    arr

let euler023() = 
    absums() //the array lookup
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i isAbsum -> if isAbsum then 0 else i) //mapi: i is the position in the sequence
    |> Seq.sum

//I always write a test once I've solved a problem.
//In this way, I can easily see if changes to the code breaks stuff.
let test() = euler023() = 4179871
```

Execution time: 0.22 seconds (!).

This is what I like so much about F#, it still allows you to use mutable constructs to tinker under the hood of your algorithm. But I still only do this *after* I've made something more elegant work first.

Comment: nice! Array could be replaced with bitarray to save some space. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple functional solution that is shorter than your original and over 100× faster:

```
let problem23 =
  let rec isAbundant i t x =
    if i > x/2 then x < t else
      if x % i = 0 then isAbundant (i+1) (t+i) x else
        isAbundant (i+1) t x
  let xs = Array.Parallel.init 28124 (isAbundant 1 0)
  let ys = Array.mapi (fun i b -> if b then Some i else None) xs |> Array.choose id
  let f x a = x-a < 0 || not xs.[x-a]
  Array.init 28124 (fun x -> if Array.forall (f x) ys then x else 0)
  |> Seq.sum
```

The first trick is to record which numbers are abundant in an array indexed by the number itself rather than using a search structure. The second trick is to notice that all the time is spent generating that array and, therefore, to do it in parallel.